# How to ls with globbing for hidden files?

Tags: ls, wildcards, dot-files

Why the following doesn't include hidden files ?

```
ls -a *vim*
```

that will return

```
 ls: cannot access '*vim*': No such file or directory

ls -a | grep vim 
.vim
.vimrc
```

Comment: Also, shell globs (filename pattern matches) are not the same as regexes in the usual sense. (As used by `sed` etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are explicitly looking for hidden files use a pattern that starts with dot,

```
ls .*vim*
```

Then there's no need for the -a flag.

Answer (score 8):

It's the shell that finds the filenames matching the pattern, not `ls` itself. So you have to get the shell to include names starting with a dot, either using `shopt -s dotglob` before the `ls` command, or by specifically including the dot in the pattern: `.*vim*`. Though note that if the pattern matches directories, `ls` will list their contents (and this is where `-a` will matter, since now it's `ls` listing the files). To prevent that, use `ls -d`.

Comment: Without using `shopt -s dotglob`, how to tell the shell to matches both **file** and **.file**? I would like `ls *file*` to show both of them. I am thinking of regex like `ls .?*file*` but it does not work.

Comment: @midnite, you'd do `ls *file* .*file*`, and by default you'd get an error from `ls` if one of them doesn't match; and in zsh or if `failglob` is set in Bash, you'd get an error from the shell before it even runs `ls`. You could try `ls ?(.)*file*` in Bash with `extglob` set, but I'm not sure if it runs into some corner cases.

Comment: Thanks. They do not work. I think either using shell option `shopt` or using `grep`, i.e. `ls -al | grep test`.